# Protobuf type and variant array types

Tags: c++, c++17, protocol-buffers

I was looking at proto3 documentation and it is not clear to me if I can create an rule for my use case. The equivalent in c++ will be to have the following declaration:

```
 using Variant = std::variant<bool, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t, float, double>;

 using Data = std::vector<std::vector<Variant>>;
```

Is it possible to describe "Data" using protobuf? From my understanding think it should probably be something like "repeated repeated Any".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a *repeated repeated Any*. Try the following code:

```
message SubData {
    repeated google.protobuf.Any element = 1;
}

message Data {
    repeated SubData sub_data = 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you kindly take a look in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307445/how-to-access-content-of-repeated-message-data)? I have initiated the approach by following this answer but could not access the elements.